# pip ignore proxy setting

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I'm trying to search/install some packages on the server using a pip through a proxy.
Server does not have direct access to https://pypi.python.org.

I run:

```
pip search --proxy 1.1.1.1:1111 lxml
```

(instead 1.1.1.1:1111 using real ip and port)

and get python trace:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  ......
  ......
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

When I try to run this command on the local computer (has direct access to https://pypi.python.org), I get the correct result:

```
 pip search --proxy 1.1.1.1:1111 lxml
 lxml                      - Powerful and Pythonic XML processing library combining
 libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API.
 ...
```

but when I run in local computer with wrong proxy settings :

```
 search --proxy blablabla lxml
```

I got correct result:

```
 lxml                      - Powerful and Pythonic XML processing library combining
 libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API.
 ...
```

This is mean that pip ignore `--proxy` settings?

UPD:

pip 1.3.1

Comment: first, try to remove `http_proxy` env variable if any; second if your proxy needs authorization add user and password: `domain\user:pwd@proxy:port`

Comment: `http_proxy` not set. proxy without authorization. I can run `curl -L -x http://1.1.1.1:1111 https://pypi.python.org` and got PyPi main page.

Comment: have you tried `https_proxy` with/without `--proxy` option which goes before/after other arguments? You could try to install latest `pip` for your user.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I have already installed the version 1.4.1 - all the same. Position argument does not solve the problem but I prefer to use `pip <command> [options]`. I have tried all combination `https_proxy` environment variable and `--proxy` setting - no effect. But when `https_proxy` set I can load https://pypi.python.org using `curl -L https://pypi.python.org`. When `https_proxy` not set I got `curl: (7) Failed connect to pypi.python.org:443; Connection refused`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an old bug of `pip` but the authors seem to choose to just ignore it. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1180 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1017